# Can you target with CSS an ID within ID?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

My example would be within an HTML file, that say you don't have access to change - only the CSS via a stylesheet. Can you target an ID within an ID the same as you can Classes?

```
#id1 #id2 {styles...}
```

similar to how you do it with CSS:

```
.class1 .class2 {styles...}
```

I could just be having a major brain fail here.

Comment: Yes you can, as long as you actually have an ID within an ID in your markup.

Comment: You can, yes. But keep in mind that ID's are uniques on the page, so you probably just need the last one. Unless the CSS file is used in multiple pages and the element may vary of container from page to page...

Comment: @BoltClock - surely it's just as valid even if you *don't* have the IDs in your markup; it just won't select anything. ;)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

yeah, like this:

```
#one #two {
    color: purple;
}
```

will select for:

```
<div id="one">
    <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

this is really not necessary though, because you are only supposed to have one id of the same name per page, so the selector `#two {}` would be fine by itself.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can do that; it's perfectly valid. But it's also generally pointless, given that an ID has to be unique within a page, so just selecting the single ID ought to always be sufficient to select exactly the element you want; you shouldn't need any additional parent selector to qualify it, whether another ID or a class or anything else.

I can see one use case for it, where you have an element with an ID that is dynamic in where is appears in the page that could appear in different locations for whatever reason, and you want it to look different according to where it in the page it appears.

For that, it might be valid to have `#id1 #id2` selector. But it's probably a fairly rare use case, and even for this usage, classes might be a more appropriate tool for the job.

Comment: Spudley is right about it being superfluous - generally. However, some single page HTML5 web apps, which use <div data-role="page"> sometimes display oddly on desktop and show more than one page element. In those cases, you may end up with more than one element with the same ID in the viewport.

Answer (score 3):

Yes

```
#id1 #id2 {

}
```

This will target all of `#id2` within `#id1`

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/DcDqa/

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can put combinators between any selectors that you like.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can

```
#id1 #id2 {
    height:200;
}
```

and also similarly

```
  .class1 #id1 {
    height:200;
  }

  .class1 input[type="radio"] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }

  h1, p{
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```
#first #second{
 color: #000080;
}
```

and

```
<div id="first">
  <p id="second">This is text and will be dark blue</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A given element, created dynamically, may require an ID in order to support some functionality. However, when the same element exists within another element, it may require different properties than when it exists within another element. So, the idea of using an ID selector within another selector may make sense in some circumstances.